# How to get "this" in handleDeepLink?

Tags: react-native

I use react native Linking in my app.

```
class AudioExample extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleDeepLink);
    }

    handleDeepLink(e){
        console.log(e.url);
        this.setState({url: e.url});  // Doesn't work here, because this it is not AudioExample class!!
    }    
}
```

How I can use this.setState({url: url}); in handleDeepLink??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to explicitly bind context with [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```javascript
componentDidMount(){
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleDeepLink.bind(this));
}
```

Another is to use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```javascript
componentDidMount(){
    Linking.addEventListener('url', event => this.handleDeepLink(event));
}
```

There are actually more approaches, but these are the best two.

Comment: bind solve this problem. But When I tried Linking.addEventListener('url', () => this.handleDeepLink());  --  "this" is ok, but, "e" (for e.url) - undefined

Comment: Ah, of course. You need to pass event object too: `(event) => this.handleDeepLink(event)`

Comment: beware binding functions inside `addEventListener`. `bind` creates a new object meaning is impossible to remove the event by calling `removeEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to bind the function to this object

```
    constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.handleDeepLink = this.handleDeepLink.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: I got this error: Error: 'this' is not allowed before super()